# Search for questions with tagA, but not tagB?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

I'm asking because of [these comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/tag-merge-request-php5-into-php/2610#2610).. Basically wondering if there's a way to find all `php5` questions without the `php` tag.

If you search for `[php5] -[php]` it goes to..

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/-php php5
```

..which returns results with the `php` tag (wrong), but if I manually correct the URL to..

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php5 -php
```

..it works perfectly (I removed `%20` from the URL for clarity)

Comment: When you type it into the search bar, it probably sorts them, when it really shouldn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order in which you place the tags matters. If you're searching for questions tagged A and not B, you'll need to put the A before the -B in the search URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php5 -php
```

Though the search exhibits bugish behavior when you place the negative term first, it's possible this is by design. Consider a search for

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/-this-tag-doesnt-exist
```

If `this-tag-doesnt-exist` doesn't exist, then that query would have to return all the questions in the system, a (potentially) costly operation.

There is, however, a bug in the display of the negated tag. Here's how it's supposed to look, [according to the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/):

[image]

However, here's how it actually looks in my browser (notice the missing "not"):

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php5%20-php This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Aha! It just doesn't work if the `-php` is first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/-php%20php5

Comment: correct, we don't allow queries to begin with `not`.