# NOT Statement Search: Searching for Posts In a Certain Tag but NOT In Another Tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

I think we need search functionality that allows searching for posts and excluding certain tag. For example, say, on Meta, I want to search for all posts in the [feature-request] tag, but not in the [status-completed] or [status-declined] tags. Can this be done currently, and if not, do you think we need it?

If we were to have this, I think that two possible ways of expressing a **NOT statement** would be:

- ![tag]
  or
- [/tag]

Comment: Dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/can-we-have-the-ability-to-filter-out-a-certain-tag-in-the-search http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10934/search-is-hard-lets-go-shopping http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/search-for-questions-with-taga-but-not-tagb and possibly others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to search for some tags, but not others, you can prepend the outcast with a minus sign, hyphen or dash (`-`):

> **[[feature-request] -[status-completed] -[status-declined] -[status-bydesign]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-declined+-status-bydesign?sort=frequent&pageSize=15)**

So in the URL for tagged: **[feature-request]**, **[tags]** not **[status-completed]**, you have:

> [feature-request+tags+-status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+tags+-status-completed)

But when you're throwing it up into the search box, you have to format it a little differently. Best when you include the tags to exclude at the end:

> [possible **[feature-request]** **[-status-completed]**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+possible+%5B-status-completed%5D+)

(You can try placing the dash outside the brackets, but results are mixed (sometimes not expected at all))

Comment: @Jeff or other StackOverflow guys; why is this not documented here? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: I missed it on the doc-page too. And: It doesn't work. I search for ellipse, which is a sequence of arguments (X x...) in Java (and C++), but also an imperfect circle, and I get lots of graphic results. Excluding -shape -paint -draw -circle doesn't help. Can I only exclude one word?