# Remove highlighting of posts with certain tag combinations?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I apologize if this question is a duplicate (I did do some searching of Meta before asking), but is it possible to remove highlighting from certain posts if one or more tags are enabled?  I know that there are [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31252/not-statement-search-searching-for-posts-in-a-certain-tag-but-not-in-another-tag) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31252/not-statement-search-searching-for-posts-in-a-certain-tag-but-not-in-another-tag) related to this idea for the search function, but there were none that I could find for post highlighting.

For example, my language of choice is Perl, and hence I'm interested in the Regex tag.  I don't really know Ruby, so I'd like to have posts with both Regex and Ruby tags to not be highlighted.  Would this be possible to do?

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) in your ignored list then posts with that tag will be dimmed. This includes posts with tags from your favourite list.

You can also hide ignored tags - from the preferences tab of your profile.

Not ideal, but gets you part way there.

Comment: Ah, I had the mistaken impression that posts with an ignored tag would not appear in the feed at all.  While not ideal, this is definitely an acceptable alternative.  Thanks!